# Staging Table location in SSIS -- Does it need to be in the same database?

Tags: ssis

I'm fairly new to SSIS and am doing a simple migration of data from a DB2 Server table to a SQL table.  In deciding how to perform an update of the data, I elected to use a Staging Table to store all the rows that have changed in some way and need to be updated.  My goal is to just do a set based update from that Staging Table to the destination to avoid having to do a row-by-row update.

The problem I am running into, and maybe it isn't a problem, maybe I'm just a newb; but, I was wondering...Does the Staging Table need to be in the same database as the table that is needing to be updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it can be in a different database if you want it to be.

Comment: Okay great.  I suppose my next question would be...how to perform the update then.

My Staging Table is in my tempdb database on my Local Transactional connection manager.  And the table that needs to be updated is on another Server.

Any help?

Comment: Well if it's on another server, then you would need to use Linked Servers to do the update.   It's possible, but I would recommend you put the staging table on the same server as the destination table if you can.   Performance will be much better.

Comment: Thank you for your quick responses!

Answer (score 0):

Well, your question makes some sense.
In general ETL scenario - no, tables can be from different DBs.
However, in Microsoft SQL, there is a technique called **partition switching** for speedy ETL process. In this technique, you partition your destination table (for example, on weekly basis), and update the whole week data by switching complete partition to staging table, updating data and switching staging table back to partition being modified. *In this particular case tables have to be in the same DB.*